# Copiar una imagen de una carpeta a otra con tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy intentando hacer un programa en tkinter que con un boton se pueda seleccionar una archivo de imagen de una carpeta de mis documentos, sin embargo no se como hacer para que al darle en guardar se guarde un una carpeta del directorio en el que se encuentra el codigo. Esto para mas adelante poder seleccionar y visualizar la imagen.

De momento el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("500x500")

def abrir_archivo():
    archivo_abierto = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                                 title="Seleccione archivo", filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpg"),
                                                                                        ("all files", "*.*")))
    print(archivo_abierto)


def guardar_archivo():
    archivo_guardado = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", defaultextension=".txt",
                                                    filetypes=(("JPEG files", "*.jpg"),
                                                               ("TXT files", "*.txt"),
                                                               ("All files", "*.*")))


    archivo = open(archivo_guardado, "w")
    print(archivo_guardado)


def carpeta():
    directorio = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if directorio != "":
        os.chdir(directorio)
    print(os.getcwd())


Button(text="Abrir archivo", bg="pale green", command=abrir_archivo).place(relx=.10, rely=.10, relheight=.1, relwidth=.3)
Button(text="Guardar archivo", bg="light blue", command=guardar_archivo).place(relx=.10, rely=.40, relheight=.1, relwidth=.3)
Button(text="Directorio", bg="salmon", command=carpeta).place(relx=.10, rely=.70, relheight=.1, relwidth=.3)

ventana.mainloop()
```

¿Alguien me podria orientar de como puedo guardar el archivo seleccionado "copiandolo" en la carpeta raiz del codigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, inicializa la variable `archivo_abierto` a nivel global:

```py
archivo_abierto = None
```

Dentro de la función `abrir_archivo` indica que la variable `archivo_abierto` es global (así la variable será accesible posteriormente dentro de la función `guardar_archivo`):

```py
def abrir_archivo():
    global archivo_abierto
    archivo_abierto = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                                 title="Seleccione archivo", filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpg"),
                                                                                        ("all files", "*.*")))
```

Ahora puedes *guardar el contenido del archivo seleccionado en un nuevo archivo seleccionado por el usuario*. Para ello modifica la función `guardar_archivo` así:

```py
def guardar_archivo():
    if archivo_abierto:
        archivo_guardado = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", defaultextension=".txt",
                                                        filetypes=(("JPEG files", "*.jpg"),
                                                                   ("TXT files", "*.txt"),
                                                                   ("All files", "*.*")))
        
        with open(archivo_abierto, 'rb') as abierto:
            with open(archivo_guardado, 'wb') as guardado:
                guardado.write(abierto.read())
```

Así, al hacer click en el botón *Guardar archivo*, se abrirá `archivo_abierto` en modo de lectura binaria (`'rb'`), y se abrirá `archivo_guardado` en modo de escritura binaria (`'wb'`) para escribir el contenido del primero en el segundo: `guardado.write(abierto.read())`.

Si lo que quieres es que el `archivo_abierto` siempre se guarde en el *directorio de trabajo del script* puedes modificar la función `guardar_archivo` así:

```py
def guardar_archivo():
    if archivo_abierto:

        archivo_guardado = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.split(archivo_abierto)[1])

        with open(archivo_abierto, 'rb') as abierto:
            with open(archivo_guardado, 'wb') as guardado:
                guardado.write(abierto.read())
```

El *directorio de trabajo del script* es `os.getcwd()`. La variable `archivo_abierto` es el *path absoluto del archivo seleccionado*, y para obtener el nombre de este archivo puedes utilizar `os.path.split(archivo_abierto)[1]`. Con `os.path.join` hemos creado el *path absoluto del archivo guardado*: `archivo_guardado = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.split(archivo_abierto)[1])`.